# CRUD code logic against SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, crud

I tried finding a solution to the following theoretical question, but couldn't - sorry if asked before, thankful for link.

**I have a client who is sending me a csv File with changing data every 60 seconds. I need to read the file and insert/update/delete entries in my corresponding DB tables.**

Currently I filter both my DB tables and the CSV File by a date of interest then I follow a two step procedure.

**1. Go through all records in the DB and check if there is a matching record in the CSV File:**

*1.1 If there is no matching record in the CSV file then I have to delete the record from the DB.*

*1.2 If there is on matching record I have to check all Fields and update the record if required.*

*1.3 If there is more than one matching record I delete all matching records in the DB.*

**2. Go through all records in the CSV File and check if there is a matching record in the DB:**

*2.1 If there is no matching record I create a new entry in the DB.*

*2.2 - Already handled in 1.2 - I do nothing.*

*2.3 If there is more than one matching record in the CSV file I contact the customer, because his CSV is corrupted.*

I am not a professional developer, but it strikes me this process is more than just tedious - the **CSV file may contain 2000-5000 records with 25 DataFields each**. Each of the steps is done using the **Task Parallel Library** for performance gains.

Is there an easier way to update my DB based on a CSV file ? 
Somehow Venn Diagramms pop into my head - essentially it is what I am already doing, but is there some inbuilt functionality in LINQ or the ADO library ?

I am using **ADO DataSets and LINQ to read and process both the CSV file and the DB Data**.

Your ideas are appreciated and your help welcomed.
Regards,

Aiolos

Comment: Yes Venn diagrams is a good call - which suggests you should use the database to do this work, as it is built around set-based logic. I would try just loading the CSV into a separate working table in the database using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) then calling a stored procedure to do joins to insert,update,delete data in the actual table. DataSet and LINQ are great for working with single or small groups of objects in your code but really aren't suited for bulk operations like this.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Integration Services to automate this entire process.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I will start looking at SQL Server Integration Services first and then have a look at SQLBulkCopy

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a pretty simple process to me.

1. Delete all entries in the database
2. Parse CSV. For each entry:

   2.1. if not in DB: create new record

   2.2. otherwise: delete record in DB and notify customer

As far as I can tell the above sequence of operations covers all your logic.